# State Space Search

Tags: searching

I searched in the web about simple example about **State Space Search**, but I didn't find any simple and clear one.

Can anybody explain to me what **State Space Search** about by a simple example? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you understand graph traversal/search?

Comment: @anorton  
If I'm right it's to find a way of visiting all the vertices of a graph, and visiting each vertex just once (avoiding redundancy)..